# How to prove Poincaré-Hopf in the non-orientable case?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, vector-fields, characteristic-classes

I understand the following proof of the Poincaré-Hopf theoerem in the case of orientable manifolds:

Proposition: Let $X$ be an oriented compact smooth manifold (without boundary).
Let $v$ be a smooth vector field on $X$ with only isolated zeros.
Then the sum of the indices of $v$'s zeros equals the Euler characteristic of $X$.

Proof:
First we note a vector field with only isolated zeros is transverse to the zero section $Z$ of $TX$. Next, identifying the Euler characteristic of $X$ as the self-intersection number of $Z$ in $TX$, w.r.t. the orientations on $Z$ (from $X$) and $TX$, and using the fact that any vector field $v$ is homotopic to the zero section (since e.g. a vector bundle total space always deformation-retracts to the zero-section), we now have $\chi(X)$ equals the oriented intersection number of $Z$ with the image of $v$; the RHS can be identified as the sum of the indices of the zeros of $v$. QED.

---

My question is, can the above be generalized to the case when $X$ is non-orientable? Since after all, we can define the index of an isolated zero of a vector field with using any orientations. Also, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) states the theorem without the assumption of orientability. However, I'm not sure how to prove the statement without assuming $X$ is orientable. Would anyone have a suggestion as to how to approach this?

Comment: The proof you sketched works fine even in the non-orientable case if you check carefully. But why not just lift everything to the orientation double-cover?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your explanation! However, I still don't quite understand your first point: how do we define the intersection number (not mod 2) if X and TX are not oriented?

Comment: Think of it instead as the self-intersection of the diagonal in $X\times X$. (By the tubular neighborhood theorem, these are the same.) Remember that $X\times X$ is orientable even when $X$ is not.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see why $X\times X$ is orientable. However, I can't see how we get an orientation on the diagonal? Is an orientation on the diagonal not needed?

Comment: You don’t, but show that $I(\Delta,\Delta)$ is likewise well-defined.